# My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS does not shutdown

Tags: boot, gnome, system-installation, shutdown

I am a new Linux user, I discovered that:

After switching from Windows 10 to Ubuntu Gnome on my HP 15 laptop, I discovered that my Ubuntu does not shutdown when I shut it down. It only gets to exit the OS and stops on the black/blank screen with a cursor that blinks for a while and stops as if I am on the bios and it remains like that. The wireless light indicator remains on, infact the system light still remains on, till I forcefully power it down.

Any solution to this would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether console 1 is running

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

and if it is (showing prompt), then log in and type

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first. As `tlp` packages aren't in a default Ubuntu installation, did you install them?

If yes, please edit the file `/etc/default/tlp` and go to the line starting with `RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST` then add `mei_me` to the end of it, so that after your edit it looks like (for example)

```
RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="radeon nouveau amdgpu iwlwifi mei_me"
```

You can do it using gedit by running: `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/tlp`. After editing that file, restart tlp service by running `systemctl restart tlp` or just reboot the machine.

If not, it's probably a power management issue and it would be good if you provide the output of the `lspci` command.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me all the time, just simply hold the power key and turn back on, that should refresh the computer and you will be able to shut down using the regular shut down button.